# What command can be used to find where Python is installed?

Tags: startup

what command? and why is so important? In UNIX? I have heilo and need to correct command.

Comment: A simple search on your favorite search engine, will yield a bucketful of useful answers.  To form an opinion, look at `$ man find`, `$ man whereis`, `$ man locate` and post the results of your trials.  Besides what Unix flavor do you use ?   [Disclaimer: I am not certain that all three manual pages are available on Unix.]

Answer (score 3):

If you need the location of an executable in your `PATH`, you can use the `which` command. For example, if I need to know where the Python executable is being called from, I can do this:

```bsh
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

If your executable isn't in your `PATH`, you can use there `whereis` command to locate extra information that you may be looking for. This gives me the binary, library, and source code:

```bsh
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3.9 /usr/local/lib/python3.9
```

Comment: It might be useful for you to add a cautionary note about the present of `shims` in the `PATH` variable, in case Python virtual environments are available on a given host ... This is becoming very common nowadays.